# How can I animate an icon?

Tags: vmware-clarity

I have an icon tag in html as:

```
<clr-icon 
  [attr.shape]="open ? (iconOpen ? iconOpen : 'caret up') : (iconClose ? iconClose : 'caret down')"
  ></clr-icon>
```

I tried applying a transition in CSS like this:

```
clr-icon {
   transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

But it doesn't animate.

Comment: You need more code or example to show what you're doing here, a transition itself doesn't toggle the properties you need more styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing:

```
<clr-icon [attr.shape]="open ? 'caret up' : 'caret down'"></clr-icon>
```

you're not binding to the direction, you're binding to the shape itself. This means whenever Angular updates that binding, it'll force the icon to re-render a brand new shape.

What you want is simply to bind the direction, and keep the shape constant:

```
<clr-icon shape="caret" [attr.dir]="open ? 'up' : 'down'"></clr-icon>
```

You can see it working fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-animate-icon?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I'm looking for.